# If I am using a local SQLAlchemy database, will it keep working if I upload it to CPanel hosting

Tags: database, flask, sqlalchemy, cpanel

I am making a web application using Flask and SQLAlchemy. Currently, the database is saved locally:

```
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
```

If I upload it to any hosting using CPanel, will the database keep functioning while saved with the other files, or do I need to change the code so I can use their database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like [cPanel gives you access to a python virtualenv](https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360057849893-How-to-install-flask-with-Python-Selector) to run flask apps, so as long as your `database.db` file is uploaded along the rest of your application, you should be able to keep using it.